# RTL wifi dongle does not create an interface at startup and doesnt connect

Tags: raspbian, wifi, usb

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with `Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)` and I am trying to use a USB Wifi dongle (`Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter`). The external wlan adapter has an external antenna with extended range.

When I restart the Pi, and check `iwconfig`, only the internal wifi interface is listed, I first have to disconnect and reconnect the dongle for wlan1 to appear. 
Running `lsmod`, I know the `r8712u` module is loaded at startup.

However, even after reconnecting the dongle I can only connect to wifi networks on wlan0 (internal) see figures 1 and 2.

[image: wlan1 appears as an interface but doesnt scan for networks]
[image: wlan1 isnt listed in the dropdown]

In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have added `auto wlan0` and `auto wlan1`, however this doesn't appear to make a difference.

I have also tried to install the realtek firmware but it is already installed

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-realtek is already the newest version (1:20161130-3+rpt4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Before I installed a fresh raspbian, I was able to see two wifi adapters and select/connect to a network with either interface. I would very much appreciate help on how to resolve this issue. Please let me know what other information I can provide which may help.

Best

Jesse

Comment: Unless you list four config files and explain why you want 2 adapters the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Milliways which config files can I provide? The external dongle has an antenna with much larger range.